# Storing mlflow artifacts to s3, while having SQL databse as backend

Tags: mlflow

When using a SQL database as backend for `mlflow` are the artifacts stored in the same database or in default `./mlruns` directory?

Is it possible to store them in different location as in AWS S3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can different artifact locations for each experiment and have the same backend registry. Here is [an example](https://github.com/dmatrix/mlflow-tests/blob/master/py/mlflow/mlflow_issues/issue_different_buckets_registry.py) that shows it

In this example, my backend registry is "mlruns.db" and the artifacts will be stored in their respective locations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make use of the mlflow serve as below.

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri=sqlite:///mlflow.db --default-artifact-root="s3://<bucket_name>" --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

Also dont forget add install boto3 and configure `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables so that mlflow can read and write from and to the bucket respectively